# Base64 image broken ios

Tags: ios, typescript, ionic-framework, base64

I have a probleme with diplaying base64 images.

When I upload an image from the camera in a base64 format i’m able to displays it via ionic devapp but when I build it from Xcode and run it natively on my ios device, the image is shown as a broken image.

Does somebody have an explanation?

Thanks!

```
private choosePicture() {
        const options = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            sourceType: 0,
            correctOrientation: true
        };

        this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {
            let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imagePath;

            let images = this.createClass.get('imagePath') as FormArray;
            images.push(new FormControl(base64Image));
        }, (err) => {
            if(err !== 'no image selected') {
                this.logError(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

and my html

```
<ion-col col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3 *ngFor="let image of createClass.controls['imagePath'].value; let i = index">
     <img src="{{ image }}"/>
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [src]="image" instead.

You could also opt to use destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI instead. What I have experience when using base64 was my app crashed when chosen image size is big.

If you opt to use file_uri, 
import {normalizeURL} from 'ionic-angular'; and use it as normalizeURL(imagePath); before displaying the image.

Hope this help.